# Equation solver in Java - Values not being pushed onto stack

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with a section of an equation solver. I have an array of Objects that hold the postfix equation, and this method evaluates each value.

The problem I'm having is that it crashes telling me that the list is empty (at this point: double num1 = ((double)operandStack.pop());)

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong here?

```
    DSAQueue<Object> postfixQueue = new DSAQueue<Object>();
.
.
.
.


private double evaluatePostfix (Queue<Object> postfixQueue)
{

DSAStack<Double> operandStack = new Stack<Double>();
while (postfixQueue.isEmpty() == false)
    {
    if (postfixQueue.peek() instanceof Double)
        {
        operandStack.push((Double)(postfixQueue.dequeue()));
        }
    else
        {
        double num1 = ((double)operandStack.pop());
        double num2 = ((double)operandStack.pop());
        char operator = ((char)postfixQueue.dequeue());
        double result = executeOperation (operator, num1, num2);
        operandStack.push(result);
        }
    }
double solution = operandStack.top();
return solution;
}
```

Comment: What arguments have you tested the method with?

Comment: My guess is that the stack is empty when this is called.  Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? (Check the content of the postfixQueue on the first iteration I bet the problem is in the first element type which is not an instance of Double and then you falling into the else case with empty operandStack)

Comment: For the record, this is an "equation evaluator" not an "equation solver".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments in code below. There seems to be a trivial code path that results in an error:

```
DSAQueue<Object> postfixQueue = new DSAQueue<Object>();

private double evaluatePostfix (Queue<Object> postfixQueue)
{

  // Here you define an empty list
  DSAStack<Double> operandStack = new Stack<Double>();

  while (postfixQueue.isEmpty() == false)
  {
    if (postfixQueue.peek() instanceof Double)
    {
      operandStack.push((Double)(postfixQueue.dequeue()));
    }
    else
    {
      // If the first item in postfixQueue was not a Double, you're now
      // pop-ing from an empty stack
      double num1 = ((double)operandStack.pop());
      double num2 = ((double)operandStack.pop());
      char operator = ((char)postfixQueue.dequeue());
      double result = executeOperation (operator, num1, num2);
      operandStack.push(result);
    }
  }
  double solution = operandStack.top();
  return solution;
}
```

If you step through with a debugger (as suggested by Peter in his comment), you can identify if this is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. In theory the first items in postfixQueue will be doubles, I guess I've made an error when putting together the postfixQueue.

Comment: Unless your `DSAQueue` class offers a shiny `toString` method, the easiest way is probably to iterate through your queue and print `toString` for each object. Note that if my answer has solved your original problem, you should really [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and post any additional problems as separate questions (after thorough research, of course).